# Change button css based on value

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to change the button css based on values. I want to have different css for Save and different css for Cancel for type button.

Ex:

```
<input type="button" value="Save">
<input type="button" value="Cancel">

save { /* Some CSS */ }
cancel{ /* Some CSS */ }
```

NOTE : I cannot use class as all the input is having same class as there are plenty of buttons. Also I dont want to use Jquery.

Comment: in css use input[value=save]{.......}

Comment: @Tommy I have edited the question. If i target value directly it will effect the textbox with text save. I want to target type button with save value. Is that possible ?

Comment: input[value=save][type=button]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, with an attribute selector.

```css
input[value="Save"] {
  color: red;
}
input[value*="Cancel"] {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Save">
<input type="submit" value="Cancel">
<input type="text" value="Cancel-me-too">
```

To target specific button type you need more than one attribute selector

```css
input[type="submit"][value="Save"] {
  color: red;
}
input[type="submit"][value*="Cancel"] {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Save">
<input type="submit" value="Cancel">
<input type="text" value="Save">
```

Comment: I have edited the question. If i target value directly it will effect the textbox with text save. I want to target type button with save value. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS Attribute Selectors :

```
input[value="Save"] {background:green;}
input[value="Cancel"] {background:grey;}
```

Comment: I have edited the question. If i target value directly it will effect the textbox with text save. I want to target type button with save value. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

I think jquery seems to be no need.
Button is large, the class must be used.
Try this code.

```
<style type="text/css">
input[value="Save"] {
  color: green;
}
input[value*="Cancel"] {
  color: black;
}
</style>
<input type="submit" value="Save">
<input type="submit" value="Cancel">
```

Comment: I have edited the question. If i target value directly it will effect the textbox with text save. I want to target type button with save value. Is that possible ?